# PHP Error while pulling excel report

Tags: php, import-from-excel

I get the following error while trying to pull the excel report. I remember the error occurred previously, not sure if increasing the PHP memory fixed it. Please Suggest.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Worksheet!W529 -> Formula
Error: Operator '-' has no operands' in C:\xampp\htdocs\asia\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:307
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\asia\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5\Worksheet.php(460): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\asia\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5.php(194): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5_Worksheet->close()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\asia\xlsheet.php(201): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('DailyTrack14_13...')
#3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\asia\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 307
```

Comment: so what's in cell W529 of your worksheet?

Comment: this is content related error, the cell has formula tag on oi but and content like A1- or -B2 or something similar, 2 way to fix remove formula from a column or fix the content

Comment: @volkinc `=-B2` wouldn't be an issue, because that's using `-` as a unary negation operator; but you're right that `=A1-` would cause a problem

Comment: @volkinc Thanks a Lot. That Fixed. Appreciate it very much :)